# Store JPA auditing timestamp in milliseconds

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Instead of storing the timestamp in Date/Timestamp format, I want to store it as milliseconds i.e. System.currentMillis();
Also, what is the recommended format while dealing with timestamps/dates with database.

Below is my auditing class

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class Auditable {

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "crt_date")
    Date createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "upd_date")
    Date updatedDate;

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(Date updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

}
```

Comment: What database engine?

Comment: Why not use the appropriate date-time type?

Comment: I am asking for recommendation as well

Comment: MySQL  & Postgres

Comment: please post details as edits to your Question, not as Comments.